# Can't play this video. video view in android Studio getting error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

> I am trying to play a video in Android studio using video View by giving the path it is stored in raw folder you can check it in the screenshot but on the emulator, it shows me **can't play this video** I even tried other answers to similar questions to this
> this is `activity_main.xml`

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/testView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="308dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.574"/>
```

this is `MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.video_player

import android.net.Uri
import android.net.Uri.*
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.testView);
        //Creating Media Controller
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
        //specify the location of media file
        val uri:Uri = parse(
            "android.resources://" + packageName
                    + "/raw/test"
        )
        //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()



    }
}
```

[image: image of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be here:

```kotlin
val uri:Uri = parse(
    "android.resources://" + packageName
            + "/raw/test"
)
```

The above way may not be able to retrieve the targeted video. Try the following instead:

```kotlin
val uri:Uri = parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.test)
```